# Propagate back press event to system

Tags: android

I am trying to create a overlay in android, which will work as block screen. What I want is, if my block screen overlay is at top and user presses back screen then in that case my block screen should get dismiss without blocking the back press event.
ie. if any third party A application is launched and on top of that my block screen is displayed. Then on press of device back button, my block screen as well as application A should removed.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: I'm not quite sure of what you want. Do you want to perform a back press on the activity of other application or on the launch screen?

Comment: I am developing a app locker application. What I want is when user launch any blocked app, a block screen should come on top of that application. And when user press back key, my block screen as well as blocked app should get the back press event. I dont want to handle back key for another application but just want to propagate this event to blocked application.

Comment: So you don't actually want to propagate the back press event to the blocked application, but send the application to the background (like the user was exitting it), correct?

Comment: yes...like user has pressed back key on that another application.

Comment: Nope, if the user presses the back key on other applications it can perform an action within the application. Not send it to background.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en this application is doing the same. So it should be possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73919/discussion-between-holandago-and-kumar-ranjan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to close the application as if the home button was pressed, you can always perform it through an Intent:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

This will send your application to background and the one you're set on top of.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it will not actually "close" any apps, but just result in `onPause` being called due to the launcher moving into the foreground

Comment: If i have multiple launcher installed it will show a chooser dialog.

Comment: Fair enough, changed it to send to background.